# Filtering by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a Date type column where are values in this format

```
1.1.2012 10:10:11
```

I need to create a filter which would filter these values by day, month and year.

I've tried

```
where like '% 1.1.2012 %'
```

but this seems to not working.

Comment: you have listed both sql server and oracle which one you are you working on?

Comment: Dates are not varchars (or strings if you prefer). You can change the format used to display the date without changing its value. Furthermore which kind of DB are you using? The answer depends on this info.

Comment: I'm interested in both solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle not store your date field formatted, but you can format the output with `to_char` function. For example:

```
select to_char(date_field,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

If you query a date without formatting, the output format will depend on the tool that you are using and your [NLS_DATE](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_date_format_sysdate.htm) parameter too.

To filter dates in Oracle you can use the `to_date` function, that receives an string and parse to date with some specific format. You can see all options of `to_date` [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Options to filter your date field:

```
where date_field between to_date('1.1.2012 00:00','d.m.yyyy hh24:mi') and to_date('1.1.2012 23:59','d.m.yyyy hh24:mi')

-- you possibly will lost some performance with this second one 
where trunc(date_field) =  to_date('1.1.2012','d.m.yyyy')
```

Answer (score 2):

In MSSQL, you can use date-functions, that are easy to handle. One way would be like this:

```
where Year (date) = 2012
and Month(date) = 1
and Day (date) = 1
```

But there are other solutions. Take a look at the following page for mor information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

I worked recently with string-representations of datetime-values. I recommend not do it and to work always with the dates, because of compatibility, speaking of the MSSQL-Server.

If you use string-representations of datetime-values you need to be very careful with formats on different language-settings than the one on your own server.
Strings can be interpreted different on other servers (ISO-format vs us-format).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to do something like this:

```
WHERE date_and_time >=to_date( '01.01.2012','dd.mm.yyyy') and date_and_time <= to_date('01.01.2012','dd.mm.yyyy');
```

date_and_time is the name of your Date column.

edit: This is for Oracle

Comment: What about `between` for further simplification?

Comment: @Ben you are right. I somehow totally forgot about that. It would be `WHERE date_and_time between to_date( '01.01.2012','dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date('01.01.2012','dd.mm.yyyy');`